# timezone clarification in java / android

Tags: android, date, datetime, timezone, locale

I have the below code

```
public Long getEpochTime(String dateToGetItsEpoch) throws ParseException
{
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    final String REQUEST_DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy h:m";

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(REQUEST_DATE_FORMAT);
    Date localDate = format.parse(dateToGetItsEpoch);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
    cal.setTime(localDate);

    format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    final String utcTime = format.format(cal.getTime());

    Date d = cal.getTime();

    return d.getTime();
}
```

If I change the locale of my device to whatever, I always get the UTC time as the return value. Which is correct, however I want to know how is this happening ? How does the device know Which timezone is the date I am giving to it so that it calculates accordingly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Date` doesn't have a time zone at all. A `SimpleDateFormat` does as a default for parsing and formatting; a `Calendar` does too; a `Date` doesn't.

Given this sequence of operations:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(REQUEST_DATE_FORMAT);
Date localDate = format.parse(dateToGetItsEpoch);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
cal.setTime(localDate);

format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
final String utcTime = format.format(cal.getTime());
```

... you're initially *parsing* the string using the default time zone of the device, then you're *formatting* it in UTC. Note that the `Calendar` part is irrelevant here - you'd get the same result with:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(REQUEST_DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = format.parse(dateToGetItsEpoch);
format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
final String utcTime = format.format(date);
```

I would personally recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) where possible for date/time work in Java, mind you. It's a much cleaner API than `Calendar`/`Date`.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. If I apply your suggested method, how do I get the new UTC time in epoch ? and regarding to your line 'you're initially parsing the string using the default time zone of the device'.. we are doing that here right ? Date localDate = format.parse(dateToGetItsEpoch); and this happens by default ?

Comment: @tony9099: I don't know what you mean by "the new UTC time in epoch". But yes, when you call `format.parse` without having specified a time zone (or calendar) on the `SimpleDateFormat`, it will use the default time zone.

Comment: I mean, how can I convert the 'utcTime' into an epoch time if I do not have it inside date using your second suggested method.

Comment: @tony9099: Again, what do you mean by "an epoch time"? You can just return `date.getTime()`. A `Date` doesn't have a time zone - it's *always* a "millis since the unix epoch" wrapper, basically. So when you parse the string using the default time zone, it's converting it into that value already.

Comment: @Johskeet, sorry I did not know that. Thanks a lot,, now utcTime is already in millies. Thanks a million for clarifying this to me.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18482920/642706) is correct. Here is some code updated to use the modern *java.time* classes that have supplanted the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

## Formatting pattern

Define a formatting pattern to match your inputs.

By the way, yours is a poor choice of formats. Instead I recommend using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats designed for exchanging date-time values as text.

### 12-hour versus 24-hour clock

Your input data or formatting pattern has a flaw. You used lowercase `h` which means one or two digits for an hour in the 12-hour clock (rather than 24-hour clock, which is uppercase `H` or `HH`). So your input makes no sense unless you add some indicator of `AM` or `PM`. I will assume you mistakenly omitted this from your Question's code.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu h:m a" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Parse such strings as `LocalDateTime` objects, as they lack an indicator of the intended time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
String input = "23/01/2020 4:5 PM" ;

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2020-01-23T16:05

## Moment

The `LocalDateTime` object we obtained above does *not* represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline. We have a time of around 4 PM on the 23rd. But we cannot know if this was meant to be 4 PM in Tokyo, Toulouse, or Toledo — all very different moments several hours apart.

To determine a moment, we must know for certain the intended time zone. Then apply that zone as a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then we have arrived at a moment.

## `Locale` is not a time zone

> locale of my device to whatever

A **`Locale` has *nothing* to with time zone**. A `Locale` is used for localizing generated text representing a date-time object.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( l )
;
String output = myZonedDateTime.format( f );
```

You could have an engineer from Québec who uses the `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` for human language and cultural norms, but while visiting in Japan uses `Asia/Tokyo` time zone for scheduling appointments.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Back to your `LocalDateTime` object. If you are certain it was meant to represent a moment as seen in the wall-clock time in Tunisia, then apply a time zone of `Africa/Tunis`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

You asked:

> How does the device know Which timezone is the date I am giving to it so that it calculates accordingly ?

You were using terrible date-time classes that failed to account for the concept of a date-time lacking an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So technically, your code is a mess, a hack, unavoidable in those days before *Joda-Time* and its successor, *java.time*.

I suggest spending *no* effort on trying to understand that behavior of `Date` & `Calendar`. Just move on to using *java.time*, the industry-leading date-time handling framework.